# Is luxury vinyl tile cost effective?

Tags: tile, vinyl-flooring

I am about to tile my bathroom floor, and a friend pointed me to this [Luxury Vinyl Tile](http://www.homedepot.com/allure)

Basically, I'm wondering if the money savings, and ease of installation will hurt me in the long run when I go to sell in 3 to 5 years. Or in other words, should I just suck it up and install ceramic tile.

Comment: This sounds like something you should discus with a real estate agent, and will depend on the housing market in your area, personal preference, and many other factors.  In some markets vinyl tile is the way to go, since you may not see a return if you spend more for ceramic tile.

Comment: Double check the savings and ease of installation, ceramic tile may not be much different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd echo what Tester101 is saying. Going with vinyl vs cermaic is really a question of the style and price of home in relation to others in the area. Whether the price of the house is dramatically affected by this decision is hard to tell.

Does it match the rest of the house? For example, if your bathroom has a walk-in glass shower that's done in granite tile, granite counter tops, and a $600 vanity, then yes, using vinyl tile will make the whole thing look cheap. If your bathroom is more modest, then you can get away with these tiles.

Houses in a given area typically sell in a certain range. If you put several thousand dollars into high-end everything then you'll probably be able to sell at the top of that range, but no one is going to pay $350k for a house in a neighbourhood where all the houses are $220 to 260k.

That said, the straight-up price difference to DIY is not that much. I actually just installed these exact vinyl tiles in my bathroom. I went with them for a couple reasons:

- I don't really like cold tiles, and so factoring in a in-floor heating ups the cost
- My house does not have a lot of high-end finishes, and is not worth enough overall that I'd get a return on investment from this.
- To put in tiles, I'd have to significantly beef up the subfloor, and I didn't want to put that much money or time in.
- I have not tiled before, and was trying to complete this project in a weekend while the wife was gone as it's our only shower and she was not thrilled at not having a shower.

Overall I'm pretty happy with them. They do take some playing with to get them perfect (especially if your walls aren't perfectly square, like mine) - the first row is critical. I messed mine up a little bit, and there's a very slight crack between them, but it's not too bad.

I also noticed that the "grout" lines on the edges are not perfectly uniform. Some are skinnier than others. I unfortunately ended up with two planks with skinny edges butted against each other, next to two with thick edges. It's subtle, but it's the sort of thing that once you see it, you can't un-see it. If I used them again, I would take a whole bunch out of the box, and lay them out before hand to make sure the edges are balanced.

[image]

I am happy with the way they turned out. It's about equivalent to a normal vinyl sheet floor. It's not even comparable to the old peel-and-stick tiles. I definitely noticed in the store that there are some that don't look that nice, and if you do a bad job at installation for sure they won't look good. My first try at it, I had the first row misaligned and so by the time I was just a few planks in, it was horribly offset. I had to go back and redo it all (which luckily, you can do).

Here's part-way through the installation, to give you an idea of how they go down:

[image]

Comment: Agreed on the cold tile aspect ... and I'd go for vinyl in a kitchen, too ... ceramic tile is hard on the back when standing for long times ... and the vinyl is friendlier to the occasional dropped glass or plate (less likely to break), and more resilient to dropped items (ie, the tile won't crack when the pot gets knocked off the counter).  It might also be worth looking into the stuff that comes in 6' wide rolls so you don't have to deal with the alignment issues.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think it is worth it.  A realtor may be able to give you a better answer for your area in regards to what buyers expect for your type of home.  I think tile is nicer and not much harder to put in.

A friend recently redid their whole kitchen (themselves) including new cabinets and granite counters, and they used this type of flooring.  I was not there when he installed it but I can tell you looking at it when it is done, it looks like the cheapest part of the project.  They chose a fake tile look and I think they really should have just done it in tile.  Even the cheapest tiles would look better than this (IMO).

This is a personal, subjective choice but I don't think it is a good look.  If you stick to ceramic it can be easy to cut.  Even porcelain tile can be cut easily (with a fresh blade) in a wet saw (you can either rent one or buy a really cheap one).

Answer (score 0):

My wife hates ceramic tile.  So if we were your prospective buyers, the LVT would be a plus. Not a lot of folks in the building industry want to hear this - but not everyone thinks ceramic tile is better even at the exact same cost.

Answer (score 0):

Look, lets be honest, vinyl tile screams "cheap".

It's ugly, you'll never get your money back when selling your home with this type of floor & It will detract from the home's selling price because the first thing people think when they see it is: $$$ "Oh my gosh we are going to have to get rid of these floors"!  Believe me, that amount is going to be deducted from the offer price of your home when you're ready to sell.

Ceramic tiles will last virtually forever, look beautiful & add value. My thinking is to do a job right the first time. Why throw good money after bad? Just save your money until you can do one project the right way.